# Unable to perform Add-Member: "Array dimensions exceeded supported range."

Tags: arrays, powershell, properties

I have an object named **$restoreItems** that I would like to filter for duplicates property values and select the most recent one.

Please have a look at its members first to understand what I'm working with:

[image]

In order to be able to check for duplicates I need a combination of the 'DirName' + 'LeafName' properties as this combination builds a complete file path.

This is my first issue. I am not able to combine the two properties and add it to that object. I tried to add a new member like so:

```
$restoreItems | Add-Member -NotePropertyName fullPath -NotePropertyValue 
($restoreItems.Dirname + '/' + $restoreItems.LeafName)
```

This command runs fine but upon calling

```
$restoreItems.fullPath
```

I get an error stating **'Array dimensions exceeded supported range.'**

Is there another way to add **$restoreItems.Dirname + '/' + $restoreItems.LeafName** to the object? If so I could probably find a way to exclude duplicates according to their  **DeletedDate** property.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Here's .GetType() for the object:

[image]

Comment: What do you get from `$restoreItems.GetType()`? Please edit your question with this information.

Comment: `$restoreItems` is an collection yes? `$restoreItems.Count`. I think you need to add those properties to each individual object of the collection. Not the collection as a whole. `$restoreItems | %{Add-Member -NotePropertyName fullPath -NotePropertyValue 
($_.Dirname + '/' + $.LeafName)}`. That being said you do not need to add that property you can just use that logic with something like `Compare-Object` as well.

Comment: @EBGreen: I added a screenshot of for .GetType(). However, it looks the same before I try to add the member to it.

Comment: @Matt: I will try adding the individual properties for ForEach-Object. When you suggest that my logic could be implemented with Compare-Object, would I have to create a calculated property for .DirName + .LeafName in order to compare .DeletedDate?

Comment: So yeah, I had assumed it was an array I just wanted to check. The answer from Ansgar Wiechers should handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement

```
($restoreItems.Dirname + '/' + $restoreItems.LeafName)
```

builds an array of all dirnames, the string "\", and all leafnames.

What you actually want is something like this:

```
$restoreItems | ForEach-Object {
    $fullname = Join-Path $_.DirName $_.LeafName
    $_ | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name FullName -Value $fullname
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I see that $fullname is of BaseType System.Object instead of System.Array. However, why is that so? .GetType() on $restoreItems.DirName for example shows System.Array. Therefore, I would assume that the Member I add does not need to be of type System.Object.